# how to make content's title unique

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am new to drupal and i want my content title unique so is there any module available for it or if i can implement autocomplete to view my past title name.
please give answer in detail

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://drupal.org/project/unique_field module. It performs additional validation when a node is created or updated by a user to require that a node's title or other specified fields are unique.

Comment: Thanks i check that module and its perfect but is there any module who work with ajax and give me same node at the same page?

Comment: you can use CCK module's autocomplete widget to extend your content type to add custom "autocompletable" title

Answer (score 0):

### Scenario #1 - Unique Node

[hook_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) is what you need, if you are working with Drupal 7

Either you can simply use this below mentioned code in your custom module or you can take a pull from [unique_title](https://github.com/RishiKulshreshtha/unique_title) git repository which you have to pull into your modules directory of your project and then activate the module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_validate().
 */
function unique_title_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  if (!isset($node->nid)) {
    $title = $form_state['values']['title'];
    $results = db_select('node')->fields('node', array('title'))->condition('title', $title, '=')->execute();
    $matches = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      $matches[$result->title] = check_plain($result->title);
    }
    if (isset($matches) && !empty($matches)) {
      form_set_error('title', t('Title must be unique'));
    }
  }
}
```

### Scenario #2 - Autocomplete Node Title

[hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) & [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) can help you in this for the autocomplete of Node titles while working with Drupal 7.

Either you can simply use this below mentioned code in your custom module or you can take a pull from [autocomplete](https://github.com/RishiKulshreshtha/autocomplete) git repository which you have to pull into your modules directory of your project and then activate the module.

In your custom module use the below mentioned code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['title']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'unique_node_autocomplete_callback';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function module_menu() {
  $items['unique_node_autocomplete_callback'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'autocomplete_unique_node_autocomplete_callback',
    'file' => 'module.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

In your module.inc file use the below mentioned AJAX callback:

```
/**
 * AJAX Callback
 */
function module_unique_node_autocomplete_callback($string = "") {
  $matches = array();
  if ($string) {
    $result = db_select('node')
      ->fields('node', array('nid', 'title'))
      ->condition('title', db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
      ->range(0, 10)
      ->execute();
    foreach ($result as $node) {
      $matches[$node->title . " [$node->nid]"] = check_plain($node->title);
    }
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```